# Как определить зависимость между двумя рядами

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Есть некая сортировка, которая в процессе работы динамически получает блоки памяти размером sqrt(N), N - количество элементов сортируемого массива. (*Этот размер IMHO к сути вопроса отношения не имеет, но все-таки...*)

Сортирую случайные данные, получаемые rand() (Linux, RAND_MAX = 2^31-1).

**Нужно определить зависимость K (количество блоков) от N (размер массива)**.

Я чувствую, что она какая-то логарифмическая (по крайней мере в некотором диапазоне(ах) N), но подобрать не получается. Для многих данных видно удвоение K при увеличении N в четыре раза. Как это математически записывается ?

```
 N      K
1000    3
2000    4
4000    5
8000    6
12000   7
16000   9
24000   10
32000   11
48000   12
50000   12  
56000   13  
64000   15  
70000   15  
75000   16  
100000  16  
150000  21  
200000  24  
280000  29
300000  31
400000  33
500000  37
600000  41
800000  48
1000000 54
1200000 57
1600000 68
2000000 78
2400000 81
3200000 95
4000000 105
6400000 131
12800000 189
16000000 211
64000000 420
```

*Если будут вопросы (в т.ч. по непосчитанным K,N) задавайте не стесняясь, посчитать не проблема. Для больших N (N > 10000000) можно не беспокоиться.*

*Про форум для математиков мне известно, но боюсь, что там мы будем говорить на разных языках. Наверняка очевидные математикам вещи будут мне не слишком понятны.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- После визуализации предоставленного вами `dataset'a` можно сразу заметить, что искомая зависимость - сублинейная и дальше подобрать коэффициенты в выражении `K = b * (N ^ a), 0 < a < 1`
- Конкретно для вашего случая хорошей аппроксимацией будет функция с параметрами *`{ a=0.492`, `b=0.061` }*, то есть

> **`K = 0.061 * (N ^ 0.492)`**

- *Зеленым* на графике изображена предложенная мной функция, *синим* - визуализированный исходный набор данных:

[image]

---

- *А это - `practical proof of concept` того, что исходная зависимость не является логарифмической)*

[image]

Comment: Потрясающе. Это надо осознать... 

N ^ 0.492 это почти sqrt(N) ? Или я ошибаюсь ?

Я, если честно, исходя из алгоритма думал, что будет (log N, x) (это если log их Emacs x - в emacs-ом help называется base) (Вообще уже всю такую математику забыл). Так вот, x я думал, будет около 1.5 или 1.25, поскольку по сути 1/4 от длины слияемого массива в очередь отправляется... 

@Котик_хочет_кушать, я если откровенно, во второй график не въехал. У Вас похоже какой-то "САПР" математический.   Не посмотрите, вот такой "дробный" логарифм, он плохо ложится ?

Comment: @avp

 - Да, `N ^ 0.492` - это примерно `N ^ (0.5)`, т.е `sqrt`.

 - Мне сложно делать какие-либо предположения насчет алгоритма, о котором я ничего не знаю :)

 - Второй график позволяет предполагать, что функция зависимости зависимости для данных, которые вы предоставили, не может быть точно выражена с в виде `a * ln(N)`.

Comment: @avp

- Собственно, можно утверждать, что в вашем случае в формуле `a * log N` для любого `a` найдется некоторое число `N` такое, что начиная с этого самого числа `N` график `a * log(N)` будет лежать ниже графика реальной зависимости. **То есть, как бы мы ни старались подобрать зависимость, представляя ее в виде `a * log(N)`, у нас это не получится.**

Comment: @Котик\_хочет\_кушать, огромное спасибо.

Как Вы считаете следует описать это количество выделяемой памяти ? 

Там блоки по sqrt(N). Я написал X \* sqrt(N) где X = ??? . Теперь вместо X написать 0.061 \* (N ^ 0.492), или просто 0.06 \* N ? 

Алгоритм (и программу) на днях планирую представить сообществу.

Comment: @avp

- Теория алгоритмов и [**Big O нотация,**][1] вообще говоря, достаточно нетривиальные штуки :)

- Во-первых, некоторый полученный набор данных не может являться строгим обоснованием для того, чтобы сказать: *"Ребята, этот алгоритм имеет емкостную сложность `O(log N)"`*

- Во-вторых, `0.06 * sqrt(N)` и `410241 * sqrt(N)` - это все `O(sqrt(N))`


[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @avp

- Емкостная сложность сильно зависит от выбранного *весового критерия.* Ваши текущие результаты, судя по всему, верны для *равномерного* весового критерия, но, скорее всего, будут некорректныдля *логарифмического* весовго критерия.

- Я пока не знаю, как вы собираетесь оформлять ваш алгоритм, но, вероятно, ***приемлемой записью будет `O(sqrt(N))` с замечанием о малой величине константы с практической точки зрения.***

Comment: Это я понимаю, поэтому и начал спрашивать. 

Я имел в виду, что в конце-концов у меня получается  *O(N)*, т.к. sqrt(N) \* sqrt(N) \* 0.061 это *O(N)*.

Про строгое обоснование  времени работы и емкости мы еще поговорим (я надеюсь) и сообщество сможет его найти.